# EXTJS4 tutorial information needed

Tags: extjs4, sencha-architect

Looking for EXTJS4/senchaArchitect tutorials in detail, I went through the sencha docs but i would like to have more information or examples on the same.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sencha tutorials are the most complete tutorials on sencha I know of.

Generally they give you a direction, and the api docs are sprinkled with enough examples to get stuff working.

You can however also check out their video channel http://vimeo.com/channels/sencha .

Comment: Except they're bug-ridden and narrowly focused.

Comment: Generally they give you a direction, and the api docs are sprinkled with enough examples to get stuff working. - I still hold this to be true. The api docs rock once you have a clue of what you are looking for.